# SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate for windows machine

Tags: git, azure, ssh, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I am facing a problem while cloning a repository from the Azure DevOps to my Windows machine. I have created ssh-key and added to Azure DevOps public key section as it is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops).

But I get this error every time

> Unable to negotiate with  port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa
> Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
> Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I have checked other links(e.g. [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61130895/unable-to-clone-azure-devops-repository-via-ssh-password-required) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71735056/cloning-from-azure-devops-using-ssh-config) [Link3](https://pantheon.io/docs/ssh-keys)) to solve this issue. But none of them is working for me. I had no problem before for cloning the repository. But recently I have changed my machine, and it is not working in my new machine. I am using Visual Studio 2019 to clone the repository.

Comment: `HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa` from the second link is the solution. Just provide the correct `Host`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working. @phd

Comment: We need to see the details — the host name from Git and `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: It works with https. And other team members also https not ssh. Unfortunately, it is as it is